# Can git continuously commit changes made to a file?

Tags: git, ubuntu-14.04

I've been working on a few fairly small projects in git, but I often find that I'm too lazy to bother committing all the time when I make a lot of small incremental changes. So, when I turn around and want to figure out the last time my code worked, I realize that I didn't save a commit. I was wondering: is there a way to get git to log a commit every time I save one of my files for me? I don't care about commit messages; I just want my changes logged.
I ran into [git stashing](https://git-scm.com/book/no-nb/v1/Git-Tools-Stashing) when I googled this question; it reduces the amount of work I have to do, but it doesn't eliminate it.
Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Just for your understanding of what git is exactly: git can't do anything automatically, since it is not a program running in the background. git is a set of scripts that only runs when you do git stuff in the command line or when a third party application uses git. So the simple answer is: git definitely can't, but maybe something else (using git) can.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Git does not autocommit, but you can set up a small script to do it for you if you like:

```
while sleep 60; do git commit -m 'Working'; done
```

This will autocommit with the message 'Working' every 60 seconds. There are also many tools like [Guard](https://github.com/guard/guard) that will watch your file system and execute something on save the way you want, but I'm not worried about the details because...

---

Now that the solution is out of the way, let's talk about your problem, because this isn't going to help. Instead of not having the last good state saved, you'll have an infinite number of partial states to look through, with no indication of what you were doing when. Maybe you'll remember to add another commit when you reach a milestone, but you just autocommitted, so there's nothing to commit to mark it (use `git commit --allow-empty` in this case), and if you remember to do this, you don't need the autocommit.

Really what you want to do is develop the habit of committing small, coherent changes. These let you go back to a prior state, but also act as breadcrumbs describing your thought process to both your future self and anyone you might work with. If you write a [good commit message](http://tbaggery.com/2008/04/19/a-note-about-git-commit-messages.html) with each, even better.

The other benefit of committing regularly is it makes you to break down your work into these small committable chunks, which can trickle all the way back to the way you're designing your code. We always hear that modularity is good, that the single-responsibility principle is good; well, this is a concrete way of building those even better habits into your process.

You'll start noticing that not only can your problem be decomposed into good commits, but parts of it are actually totally independent. Those can be put onto different branches, letting you switch between them as you like or need to and merge later into `master` or each other. That's especially helpful for anyone reviewing your code, since they can read features A and B and bug C one at a time, instead of in one megachangeset.

Get yourself a timer and have it go off every 5 minutes (pick a period that feels usefully frequent without interrupting your train of thought too often). Whenever it does, ask yourself if you've accomplished a step in your task, and commit it. Since at the ding you'll probably be halfway through something else, get familiar with [git add --patch](http://nuclearsquid.com/writings/git-add/) so you can stage the sections that are finished and keep working on the parts that are not. The more you learn and use Git, the more effective you'll be, and the less time you'll spend scrolling through a stream of minute changes.